# Data in 2 side by side Table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have one database having 4 columns and data upto 50 entry... I don't want to show table full page width as having only 4 columns. So thinking of show 2 table side by side which will show the data  in first table and then continued to 2 tables.
Ref. attached Images. data in the table are different for each ID.

Can anyone help to make the same  [image: 2 side by side Table] in Laravel.

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please try something yourself first

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do that with a flex container. As for separating your data in two, the collection's `chunk` method could help. The basic layout would be:

```xml
<div style="display: flex; gap: 10em; justify-content: space-between;">
    @foreach($data->chunk(ceil($data->count()/2)) as $chunk)
        <table>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($chunk as $row)
                    ...
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    @endforeach    
</div>
```

I'm sure you can do something simliar with bootstrap classes or any other thing you're using for styling.

```xml
<div class="row">
    @foreach(...)
        <div class="col-6">...</div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

There's even an example of this in the documentation

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-chunk

Comment: Thanks for Reply.... Will try and reply.... Also trying query using odd and even for table

Comment: You can just query everything from the database and then use `filter` in the view to loop over odds first, and then loop over evens.

Comment: [partition](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-partition) could also be used in the controller to get a collection of even and odds.